# Find first & last address of each occurrence (Dynamic) in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names (sorted) in a column & I want to find the First & Last address of each occurrence.

```
Table:
John
John
John
John
John
John
Micheal
Micheal
Micheal
Lucy
Jake
Jake
Jake
Jake
```

> Example:
>
> John (First - 1 & Last - 6) Micheal (First - 7 & Last - 9) and so
>   on....

I can write For Loop to iterate through each row & get the location:

```
For i = 1 To Rows.Count

Next i
```

Or I can use Find:

```
Dim Start as Long, End as Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Start = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="Micheal", after:=.Range("A1")).Row
    End = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="Micheal",after:=.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

But is there a direct approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy the data to a Variant Array, and loop that.   Unless you have 100,000s of rows that will be plenty fast enough

Comment: You can use regular excel formula to get first and last address. Like Array formula `="A" & MIN(IF($A$2:$A$15=D2,ROW($A$2:$A$15),""))`